# Get Time Difference between two datetime in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to get Get Time Difference between two datetime  in stroed procedure. then i need to cast that answer to varchar. i don't know how to get that value. i am a new one for  stroed procedure.  i am using sql server 2008

```
declare @tdate1 datetime
declare @date2 datetime
declare @finaltime varchar

set @enddate = '2004-10-18 07:53:35.000'
set @startdate = '2004-10-18 15:28:57.000'

if @startdate >= @enddate
// This is what i want to do..

else
```

Comment: Time difference in what unit of measure?  Hours?  Minutes?  Seconds?  In any case, look at `datediff`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, @startdate, @enddate)
```

try this to start you in the right direction.

`year` represents the period of measure you want to return

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) is a link to an MSDN Article that may be helpful

`DATEDIFF` (Transact-SQL)

Other Versions

*Updated: December 2, 2015*

**THIS TOPIC APPLIES TO:**

yesSQL Server (starting with 2008) yesAzure SQL Database yesAzure SQL Data Warehouse yesParallel Data Warehouse
Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.
For larger differences, see DATEDIFF_BIG (Transact-SQL). For an overview of all Transact-SQL date and time data types and functions, see Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL).
Topic link icon Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions
Syntax

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

-- Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse

```
DATEDIFF (datepart ,startdate ,enddate )
```

**Arguments**

*datepart*

Is the part of startdate and enddate that specifies the type of boundary crossed. The following table lists all valid datepart arguments. User-defined variable equivalents are not valid.

**datepart**

*Abbreviations*

```
year
yy, yyyy
quarter
qq, q
month
mm, m
dayofyear
dy, y
day
dd, d
week
wk, ww
hour
hh
minute
mi, n
second
ss, s
millisecond
ms
microsecond
mcs
nanosecond
ns
startdate
```

Is an expression that can be resolved to a `time, date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2`, or datetimeoffset value. date can be an expression, column expression, user-defined variable or string literal. startdate is subtracted from enddate.

To avoid ambiguity, use four-digit years. For information about two digits years, see Configure the two digit year cutoff Server Configuration Option.
enddate

See **startdate**.
*Return Type
int*
Return Value
Each datepart and its abbreviations return the same value.
If the return value is out of range for int (-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647), an error is returned. For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds. For second, the maximum difference is 68 years.
If startdate and enddate are both assigned only a time value and the datepart is not a time datepart, 0 is returned.
A time zone offset component of startdate or endate is not used in calculating the return value.
Because smalldatetime is accurate only to the minute, when a smalldatetime value is used for startdate or enddate, seconds and milliseconds are always set to 0 in the return value.
If only a time value is assigned to a variable of a date data type, the value of the missing date part is set to the default value: 1900-01-01. If only a date value is assigned to a variable of a time or date data type, the value of the missing time part is set to the default value: 00:00:00. If either startdate or enddate have only a time part and the other only a date part, the missing time and date parts are set to the default values.
If startdate and enddate are of different date data types and one has more time parts or fractional seconds precision than the other, the missing parts of the other are set to 0.
datepart Boundaries
The following statements have the same startdate and the same endate. Those dates are adjacent and differ in time by .0000001 second. The difference between the startdate and endate in each statement crosses one calendar or time boundary of its datepart. Each statement returns 1. If different years are used for this example and if both startdate and endate are in the same calendar week, the return value for week would be 0.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(quarter, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(dayofyear, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(week, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'
, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
```

Remarks
DATEDIFF can be used in the select list, WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses.
DATEDIFF implicitly casts string literals as a datetime2 type. This means that DATEDIFF does not support the format YDM when the date is passed as a string. You must explicitly cast the string to a datetime or smalldatetime type to use the YDM format.
Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is deterministic.
Examples
The following examples use different types of expressions as arguments for the startdate and enddate parameters.
A. Specifying columns for startdate and enddate
The following example calculates the number of day boundaries that are crossed between dates in two columns in a table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Duration
    (
    startDate datetime2
    ,endDate datetime2
    );
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration(startDate,endDate)
    VALUES('2007-05-06 12:10:09','2007-05-07 12:10:09');
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,startDate,endDate) AS 'Duration'
FROM dbo.Duration;
```

-- Returns: 1
B. Specifying user-defined variables for startdate and enddate
The following example uses user-defined variables as arguments for startdate and enddate.

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2007-05-05 12:10:09.3312722';
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2007-05-04 12:10:09.3312722'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate);
```

C. Specifying scalar system functions for startdate and enddate
The following example uses scalar system functions as arguments for startdate and enddate.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, GETDATE(), SYSDATETIME());
```

D. Specifying scalar subqueries and scalar functions for startdate and enddate
The following example uses scalar subqueries and scalar functions as arguments for startdate and enddate.
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,(SELECT MIN(OrderDate) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader),
    (SELECT MAX(OrderDate) FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader));
```

E. Specifying constants for startdate and enddate
The following example uses character constants as arguments for startdate and enddate.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2007-05-07 09:53:01.0376635'
    , '2007-05-08 09:53:01.0376635');
```

F. Specifying numeric expressions and scalar system functions for enddate
The following example uses a numeric expression, (GETDATE ()+ 1), and scalar system functions, GETDATE and SYSDATETIME, as arguments for enddate.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2007-05-07 09:53:01.0376635', GETDATE()+ 1) 
    AS NumberOfDays
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader;
GO
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2007-05-07 09:53:01.0376635', DATEADD(day,1,SYSDATETIME())) AS NumberOfDays
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader;
GO
G. Specifying ranking functions for startdate
The following example uses a ranking function as an argument for startdate.
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
    ,DATEDIFF(day,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
        a.PostalCode),SYSDATETIME()) AS 'Row Number'
FROM Sales.SalesPerson s 
    INNER JOIN Person.Person p 
        ON s.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.Address a 
        ON a.AddressID = p.BusinessEntityID
WHERE TerritoryID IS NOT NULL 
    AND SalesYTD <> 0;
```

H. Specifying an aggregate window function for startdate
The following example uses an aggregate window function as an argument for startdate.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT soh.SalesOrderID, sod.ProductID, sod.OrderQty,soh.OrderDate
    ,DATEDIFF(day,MIN(soh.OrderDate) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY soh.SalesOrderID),SYSDATETIME() ) AS 'Total'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
        ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
WHERE soh.SalesOrderID IN(43659,58918);
GO
```

Examples: Azure SQL Data Warehouse Public Preview and Parallel Data Warehouse
The following examples use different types of expressions as arguments for the startdate and enddate parameters.
I. Specifying columns for startdate and enddate
The following example calculates the number of day boundaries that are crossed between dates in two columns in a table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Duration (
    startDate datetime2
    ,endDate datetime2
    );
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration(startDate,endDate)
    VALUES('2007-05-06 12:10:09','2007-05-07 12:10:09');
SELECT TOP(1) DATEDIFF(day,startDate,endDate) AS Duration
FROM dbo.Duration;
```

-- Returns: 1
J. Specifying scalar subqueries and scalar functions for startdate and enddate
The following example uses scalar subqueries and scalar functions as arguments for startdate and enddate.
-- Uses AdventureWorks

```
SELECT TOP(1) DATEDIFF(day,(SELECT MIN(HireDate) FROM dbo.DimEmployee),
    (SELECT MAX(HireDate) FROM dbo.DimEmployee)) 
FROM dbo.DimEmployee;
```

K. Specifying constants for startdate and enddate
The following example uses character constants as arguments for startdate and enddate.

```
-- Uses AdventureWorks

SELECT TOP(1) DATEDIFF(day, '2007-05-07 09:53:01.0376635'
    , '2007-05-08 09:53:01.0376635') FROM DimCustomer;
```

L. Specifying ranking functions for startdate
The following example uses a ranking function as an argument for startdate.
-- Uses AdventureWorks

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
,DATEDIFF(day,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
        DepartmentName),SYSDATETIME()) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.DimEmployee;
```

M. Specifying an aggregate window function for startdate
The following example uses an aggregate window function as an argument for startdate.
-- Uses AdventureWorks

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, DepartmentName
    ,DATEDIFF(year,MAX(HireDate)
             OVER (PARTITION BY DepartmentName),SYSDATETIME()) AS SomeValue
FROM dbo.DimEmployee
```

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).  Here is a [demo of how to use this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8e52/3/0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, [Start], [End]) AS [Days],
   DATEDIFF(minute, [Start], [End]) AS [Minutes],
   DATEDIFF(second, [Start], [End]) AS [Seconds] FROM Dates;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to calculate the diff between two dates in days, here is my suggestion:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '01-01-2000', 
      @end DATETIME = GETDATE() 

SELECT CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, @end, @start)) AS VARCHAR(100))
```

I assumed that you will always want a positive answer, so ABS allows you to ignore the order of the dates. You mentioned in your post that you wanted the final answer as Varchar, so I included a cast.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Using DATEDIFF() you can get the seconds difference, minutes difference, Hour difference..... etc. But if you want to get the date/time difference in a clear way, you can do a this kind of thing.
.

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

select @StartDate = '04/07/2015 05:01:23.000',@EndDate='04/08/2015 10:32:30.000'

select convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) as [HH:MM:SS]
```

**Output Format will be [HH:MM:SS] : 05:31:07**

I Think this is the best way to get the time difference between two date times in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here what I've used before, very short code:

Select CAST((@EndDateTime-@StartDateTime) as time(0)) '[hh:mm:ss]'